# Will the "extends" in `tsconfig.json` merge array values?

Tags: typescript

What's the actual behavior when extending array fields in `tsconfig.json`?

For example:

`be-extended-tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types"
    ]
  }
}
```

will this config file...

```
{
  "extends": "./be-extended-tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "@nuxtjs/firebase"
    ]
  }
}
```

eventually resolved as this?

```
{
  "extends": "./be-extended-tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxtjs/firebase"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a `inspect` just like webpack to show the eventual merged content of `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It won't unfortunately :(

Reference: https://miyoon.medium.com/array-parameters-in-tsconfig-json-are-always-overwritten-11c80bb514e1

Comment: And what about objects like `compilerOptions`?

Comment: @cbdeveloper it merges `compilerOptions` -- you can see by running `tsc --showconfig`